# I made a virtual keyboard, and when I check value of display from keyboard(number), it's undefined...How I get a number as value?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

```
(HTML)
  <div class="keyboard-login">
           
                  <div class="display-login" ></div>
                   <div class="buttons">                      
                     <div class="key-btn-container">        
                         <button  class="key key-btn key_1">1</button>
                     </div>
  
                     <div class="key-btn-container">  
                         <button  class="key key-btn key_2">2</button>
                    </div>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
                  </div>

             </div>
```

```
(javascript)


keyboardLogin.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    

    console.log(loginDisplay.value);

    if (e.target.classList.contains('key_1')) {
        let valu = loginDisplay.innerHTML;
        loginDisplay.innerHTML=valu+'1';
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains('key_2')) {
        let valu = loginDisplay.innerHTML;
        loginDisplay.innerHTML=valu+'2';
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains('key_3')) {
        let valu = loginDisplay.innerHTML;
        loginDisplay.innerHTML=valu+'3';
    }
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
});
```

Hello. I'm making a virtual keyboard,
when I check 'console.log(login display.value);', it show me up 'undefined'. and I need number-value from the display element.  What can I do??  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
e.target.classList.contains('key_1')
```

by:

```
e.target.className.includes('key_1')
```

If loginDisplay is an input label, change:

```
if (e.target.classList.contains('key_1')) {
        let valu = loginDisplay.innerHTML;
        loginDisplay.innerHTML=valu+'1';
    }
```

by:

```
    if (e.target.className.includes('key_1')) {

        loginDisplay.value += '1';
    }
```